# Finding the $n$-th derivative from $e^{x^{40}}$ using Maclaurin series

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives

When looking at this problem, I found the series to be:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{{x^{40n}}}{n!}$$

When finding the $20$th and the $80$th derivative using this series, shouldn't they all be zero? I confirmed that the $20$th derivative is but the $80$th derivative isn't.

Is there a reason why?

Comment: I assume you mean derivatives at $0$? Because $$f(x) = 1+x^{40}+\frac{1}{2}x^{80}+\dots$$ so when you differentiate $80$ times the term $\frac{1}{2}x^{80}$ gives $\frac{1}{2}80!\cdot 1$ which doesn't cancel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Clement C mentions, when you differentiate $80$ times the term at $0$ doesn't cancel. Another perspective is taking the Maclaurin series of $e^x$, i.e.
$$e^y = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{y^n}{n!}$$
Now let $y = x^{40}$,
$$e^{x^{40}} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{{x^{40n}}}{n!}$$
which tells you that the exponents are multiples of $40$, i.e. everything in between is zero.